# Accessing port on guest(Windows 10) from host(Mac Catalina) using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I see similar questions have been asked but not just same. I can't find solution anyway. My situation is that I have host Mac with Catalina running on it and have created guest Windows 10 on VirtualBox. Guest has installed Python3 and Microsoft Robotic Developer Studio. Now I need to run some python code in order to drive robot in Microsoft Robotic Developer Studio. I would prefer to write and run this code from Host because first of all resolution can't be properly set up in Guest and second is that once I start Microsoft Robotic Developer Studio everything becomes extremely slow so writing commands in Powershell to run python is aggravating and also I can't be bothered to write code on Host and then drag and drop or copy/paste it into the Guest. This code works in such a way that it actually makes connection on http://localhost:50000/ and through this it will exchange json strings with the Microsoft Robotic Developer Studio. So what I believe I need is possibility to access this port from Host. Then when I run code on Host(Mac) it would be passed into Guest and through this port, and would go into Microsoft Robotic Developer Studio on my Guest. Can someone please help with this, if there is even possibility to make it work?

Comment: Ports on localhost are not accessible from other computers like the host machine. You have to find a way to change the program tat open this port to bind it to the public ip (or to to all IPs) instead of localhost.

Comment: Well my python code by default communicates by using default ip for localhost which is 127.0.0.1 and port 50000. This of course runs well if I run code on the Guest. So I can change ip in the python code for 127.0.0.1 to whichever is the IP of the Guest and the code should work when I run it on the Host? How do I check/change IP of the Guest?

Comment: Just remove the IP address. If no IP is specified usually the port is opened on all interfaces. Make sure the guest uses NAT mode to communicate with the host (not bridged). Also check the Windows firewall if the port 5000 is opened for python.

Comment: Could you please write bit more on NAT mode and checking the firewall? Also, default string used for communication is 127.0.0.1:50000. In case I remove ip it should look like :50000?

Comment: If you have to specify an ip address use `0.0.0.0`. NAT: Check VirtualBox GUI, settings of your VM -> network; Firewall: Yous your favorite Internet search on `Windows 10 firewall`.

Comment: I managed to do it but I also had to forward ports in VirtualBox settings, otherwise it would not work. I set both host and guest port 50000.